# JPanel subclass won't appear in JFrame

Tags: jframe, jpanel, subclass

I have this class PokerPanel which extends JPanel, whatever I put in the JPanel subclass will not appear in the JFrame when it is set as the Content Pane. Below is the code

```
public class PokerPanel extends JPanel {
    private int x = 1000;
    private int y = 1000;

    public PokerPanel(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);        
}
```

Then in my main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PokerPanel pp = new PokerPanel();
    pp.setOpaque(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(pp.getX(), pp.getY());
    frame.setContentPane(pp);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This does not show the black background as intended (or anything else i put in there for that matter JLabels etc), however if I do it as shown below then it does work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PokerPanel pp = new PokerPanel(rg);
    pp.setOpaque(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(pp.getX(), pp.getY());
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why it would not show the JPanel when it is a subclass of JPanel any help would be appreciated